# Icons without names

Tags: xubuntu, icons

I would like the icons of the current programs running not to show their names, like Windows 7. I am running Xubuntu 13.10, and help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the steps:

1. Right click on the panel. Select *Panel -> Panel Preferences*.
2. Go to the *Items* tab and select the "Window Buttons" item.
3. On the right side there should be a button to open the preferences for "Window Buttons", click it.

I don't have Xfce in front of me, but the option should be something like "Show title". You just need to uncheck it (I'd recommend to check the "flat buttons" option too).